# Improve SQLite writing speed C#

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite, asynchronous, pragma

I need to dramatically improve writing speed for SQLite (or maybe suggest another solution for this outside of SQLite).

**Scenario :**

- I have 71 Columns with 365 * 24 * 60 values each. (365 = days)
- I do "insert intos" for testing the db_performance
- To shorten the testing-time I did the tests for 90 days instead of 365 (so the result-timespans will be x4)

**Settings :**
I've tried various PRAGMAS like

- synchronous off
- locking_mode exclusive
- cache & pagesize with different values (though I read low values may improve performance, for me higher values did a good job)
- journal_mode off
- changing timeout values

**Approaches :**

- #A1 Gathering all "insert intos", ExecuteNonquery each, at the end do one giant transaction
- #A2 the same like above but with ParallelForEach and ExecuteNonqueryAsync
- #A3 Gathering all "insert intos" for one day and do one transaction each

**Tablestructure :**

- #T1 One table with all the columns
- #T2 One table for each column

**Results :**
I did runs for 90 days ( so it doesn't take too long ) and the main problem is writing speed.

I measured 5 phases, which are :

- #P1 setup the tables & headers ( ~ 8-9ms)
- #P2 prepare the data (for every "insert into" command do ExecuteNonquery) ( ~ 15000-18000ms ! )
- #P3 do the transaction (~ 200-500 ms)
- #P4 read one complete column ( ~80 - 200 ms)
- #P5 delete one complete column ( ~ 1 - 9 ms)

I tried all the different methods and approaches I mentioned before, but couldn't manage to improve #P2. Any ideas how to fix that ? Or maybe any hint for a better solution as a serverless db (Realm?) ?

Here's the code for the #A1 #P2 #T2, which had the best results so far...

```
using (var transaction = sqLiteConnection.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (var command = sqLiteConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        foreach (var vcommand in values_list)
        {
            command.CommandText = vcommand;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
                        
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

(values list is a string[] with 71*90 insert intos or in Marks version one giant command.)

Edit/Update :
I tried the approach by Mark Benningfield making one giant "insert into" for all values in one table with all columns and could improve the overall speed to ~8500ms (#P2 ~7500ms).

Final Update :
Ok I did a bunch of tests and will summarize the results :

For comparison reason all databases had the same values, a two-dimensional double array with [129600,71] values. None of them had a prepared insert-statement, so the generation time for transforming the values into the needed format is included (phase 2).

SQLite needs ~14seconds with one giant transaction (the previous ~8s were without generating the insert-into-command live). SQL_CE is atm the best for this scenario. This is mainly due to not operating with strings ("INSERT INTO"), but with DataTables and rows + bulkInsert. Realm is interesting, especially for mobile users - very intuitive. But you cannot add dynamic obejcts atm (so you need a static object). Influx is another nice database for timeseries, but it's very specific, not embedded and has IMHO a poor C# implementation (it may perform much better via console).

[image]

Comment: Did you see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/bulk-insert) comment about bulk inserts with SQLite? Bulk inserts do not exist in SQLite so you should re-use the same command with different parameters.

Comment: On a separate issue, a single table with 71 columns or 71 tables with a single column indicates that this is not in [3rd Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). Can you post your `CREATE TABLE` command for a single table and we might be able to point out where you can optimize your data.

Comment: TY - I will try to parametrize the values like in the description you posted and will get back to you

Comment: I tried parametrizing, so for each row I parametrize the 71 columns to one command and ExecuteNonQuery this. Unfortunately the performance doesn't go up. Maybe it would be better to parametrize all rows for each column, so you have just 71 executeNonQuery, but for now it looks like parametrizing is not a big boost..

Comment: The update you posted is NOT using my suggestion. With that code, the command has to be prepared over and over again. If you follow my suggestion, you will see an improvement.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield well in your approach I just have one (giant) transaction in the values_list...(I didn't change the code in the update at all, I will summarize my testings soon)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing the data to a text file and then using the import command (see Importing CSV files)? Unlike INSERT commands, these routines usually ignore triggers and work with direct table access.

Comment: Could you please add a link to _see importing CSV file_?

Comment: Sorry: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files

Comment: TY - Good idea, will try and comment afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Make your insert command look like this (by constructing it however you need to):

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, 'val2', val3),
    (val1, 'val2', val3),
    (val2, 'val2', val3),
    ...
    (val1, 'val2', val3);
```

Then execute the *single* insert command to do a bulk update of known data.

Comment: TY . Will try and comment on that afterwards

Comment: Ok @Mark Benningfield , I tried this - I constructed a single INSERT INTO for 71 columns with a massive amount of values (50MB txt file just for the command). #P2 (executeNonQuery) is faster this way (7678ms), but #P3 (transaction) is horribly slow (45725ms). I will try to parametrize the query as Daniel Dearlove suggested next.

Comment: Edit : I reworked my code for opening and closing connections, because your approach has caused database lock sometimes so I explicitly open and close the db for each phase now and now your approach is really fast with 8500ms @Mark Benningfield

Comment: @c_ph_r, nice to see you have improved the performance. I thought about using an in-memory SQLite database, attach a second on-disk database then stream one into the other. You could do a similar thing with the [backup](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) interface. However, I think that will only optimize the I/O and I think the index building will be done twice. It is not clear if you are currently CPU-bound or I/O-bound so it is difficult to give concrete advice. Also, is 8500ms good enough? What performance do you actually need?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did a bunch of tests and will summarize the results :

For comparison reason all databases had the same values, a two-dimensional double array with [129600,71] values. None of them had a prepared insert-statement, so the generation time for transforming the values into the needed format is included (phase 2).

SQLite needs ~14seconds with one giant transaction (the previous ~8s were without generating the insert-into-command live). SQL_CE is atm the best for this scenario. This is mainly due to not operating with strings ("INSERT INTO"), but with DataTables and rows + bulkInsert.
Realm is interesting, especially for mobile users - very intuitive. But you cannot add dynamic obejcts atm (so you need a static object).
Influx is another nice database for timeseries, but it's very specific, not embedded and has IMHO a poor C# implementation (it may perform much better via console).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and recommended way to do bulk inserts is to use prepared statements with parameters. That way, a statement (command) is only parsed and prepared once, instead of having to parse it again for every row. SQLite also does not have to parse the parameter values from the command text, but they are supplied and used directly. For each row, you only switch parameters.

So instead of going this way:

```
using (var transaction = sqLiteConnection.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (var command = sqLiteConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        foreach (var vcommand in values_list)
        {
            command.CommandText = vcommand;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
                        
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

You should do it like this:

```
using (var transaction = sqLiteConnection.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (var command = sqLiteConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        // Create command and parameters
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (?, ?)";
        var param1 = command.Parameters.Add(null, SqliteType.Integer);
        var param2 = command.Parameters.Add(null, SqliteType.Text);

        foreach (var item in values_list)
        {
            // For each row, only update parameter values
            param1.Value = item.IntProperty;
            param2.Value = item.TextProperty;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
                        
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

This will perform much better. The statement is only parsed on first execute. All following executes will use the already prepared statement. It also safeguards you against SQL Injection attacks: Text parameters are not inserted into the actual SQL statement string, which would allow manipulation of your statement. Instead, they are passed directly as values to SQLite. So you do not only gain performance, you have also prevented one of the most common database attack scenarios.

General rule: Never put values directly into SQL statements. Always use parameters instead.

Note: There are also other ways to create and parameters. This is just one example how to do it. For example, you can also use named parameters:

```
    // Create command and parameters
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (@one, @two)";
    var param1 = command.Parameters.Add("@one", SqliteType.Integer);
    var param2 = command.Parameters.Add("@two", SqliteType.Text);
```